# Аргумент, позволяющий игнорировать обязательные аргументы

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

В python при создании парсера аргументов с помощью argparse автоматически добавляется аргумент --help. Мне нужно добавить аргумент со схожим функционалом. То есть такой, при передаче которого в программу будет игнорироваться отсутствие обязательных аргументов и выполнится, например, вызов функции. При этом обязательные аргументы должны быть (нельзя их сделать необязательными)! Можно ли как-то такое сделать?

Comment: Такое можно сделать. Например, создать первичный и вторичный парсер аргументов. Конфигурация вторичного парсера будет зависеть от наличия аргумента в первичном.

Answer (score 2):

у именованных аргументов есть аргумент required, отвечающий за обязательность аргумента.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', required=True)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
Namespace(foo='BAR')
>>> parser.parse_args([])
usage: [-h] --foo FOO
: error: the following arguments are required: --foo
```

пример из документации.